# Automatically forward email attachment as textual link in another email

Tags: email, email-attachments

This might be an odd request but I know there must be a way. Here's what I have and would like to do:

```
Input:
1) An email is sent with an attachment
2) The attached file is a jpg image

Output:
3) An email should be received with a tiny link in the email body
4) The tiny link should point to the image viewable in a browser

Additional Criteria:
5) The destination email address to which the original message is sent can be altered
6) The format of the original mail cannot be altered; the image is always attached
7) The process must be automated, triggered by the original email
```

I have gmail accounts and a Linux server that could potentially be used but not sure where to start. I've searched quite a bit and found a lot of software that do similar tasks but nothing like this specifically. It seems to be a fairly complicated task and I could use some ideas. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit of a challenge but I managed to get it done. Here's how:

```
Input:
1) Send the email with attachment to local postfix smtp server

Processing:
2) Have postfix call procmail when email is received
3) Use procmail as a filter to conditionally call a script

Custom script:
4) Use munpack to convert the attachment to file
5) Use a script to upload the image file to imgur
6) Use a script to make the imgur link tiny

Output:
7) Send an email using mutt with the link in the body
```

The main problem I had was setting up postfix and finding bugs in the clients trying to send email to the local postfix server. I used an array of tutorials, IRC and tools to debug but tcpdump revealed the final smoking gun.